# address of global variable in glibc changed after add-symbol-file

Tags: c, gdb, global-variables, glibc

I'm tring to debug an application that run with a striped glibc.so I loaded symbol table with a glibc with debug information use add-symbol-file. But I found that, the address of global variable 'LogFile' in misc/syslog.c changed.
gdb info like this:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
0x747ab660 in nanosleep () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) p LogFile
$1 = 5
(gdb) p &LogFile
$2 = (<data variable, no debug info> *) 0x7484e27c <LogFile>
(gdb) add-symbol-file /nfs/glibc/libc-2.24.so 0x747221c0
add symbol table from file "/nfs/glibc/libc-2.24.so" at
    .text_addr = 0x0x747221c0
(y or n)y
Reading symbols from /nfs/glibc/libc-2.24.so...done.
(gdb) p LogFile
$3 = 0
(gdb) p &LogFile
$4 = (int *) 0x14227c <LogFile>
```

why this occured? Thanks.

Comment: If the non-stripped libc version is suitable, you could _start_ your application with that libc; eg, copy that libc to a new local dir; then within `gdb`, first `set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /full/path/to/new-dir:/other-dir:/another`, then run your application.  See `set environment` in a `gdb` manual like this [link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Environment.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Milag. non-stripped libc can avoid this problem.But I want to know why address of 'LogFile' changed.